# Need Help Implementing a Basic Binary Symmetric Channel In Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, information-theory

I am working through Cover, Thomas "Elements of Information Theory" and want to try and implement a simple example of a binary symmetric channel. That is to say, I can specify a message "1001", an encoding "11000011" (basically repeat each bit twice), a channel law: p(y|x), and I'd like to see my posterior at the receiver update.

Now in all honesty, I don't even know where to begin, and I can't seem to find much hlep online. Most of what I find is using Matlab's simulink to abstract away the process. I actually want to specify distributions as vectors, etc etc. Any pointers would be great!

Edit: I don't know if this question fits better over at DSP.SE but if so, I can move it over.

Comment: I would start by breaking the problem into smaller problems which are more solvable.  Which of these steps are you having an immediate problem with?

Comment: I guess specifying a channel law: p(y|x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary symmetric channel is just flipping bits with a certain probability.

```
x = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1];
p = 0.1; % with probability p, make an error
errorbits = rand(size(x)) < p; % toss some biased coins and make a logical index
y = x; % first perfectly copy
y(errorbits) = 1 - y(errorbits); % make 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0
```

Do you see how this is a $P(y|x)$ that implements the symmetric binary channel?

Comment: I do. thank you. But how can I incorporate a "message" that has been "encoded" in some "alphabet" using this transmission scheme?

Comment: @user79950 your message is 1001 and you encoded it as 1100000011, that's also straightforward to write in matlab. Encoding is a stage before the transmission. You can treat them independently (in most practical cases).